# LatLngBounds or CameraUpdate not show all points in Maps Lite Mode

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a map in which I show a series of points linked by Polylines, the map is LiteMode, but under certain circumstances when creating a LatLngBounds with those points and updating the camera some points are left out of the map.

```
  LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (LatLng latLng : listPoints) {
        builder.include(latLng);
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    int padding = 0; //offset from edges of the map in pixels
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    map.moveCamera(cu);
```

How can I solve that?

Through the polylines we can see that they are out of sight even by changing the *pading*:[image: 1]
And so it is seen if I remove the LiteMode:
[image: 2]]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem!
According to Google Maps Lite Mode [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite#supported_api_features) says:

> Camera position, zoom, and animation
> Supported? Partly
> You can set the camera target and zoom, but not the tilt or bearing. ***Zoom level is rounded to the nearest integer in lite mode.*** Calling GoogleMap.moveCamera() will give you another static map image. For more information on setting and manipulating the camera, see Changing the View.

My solution was to get Visible Region from the map and compare to see if any of the points on my list were outside that region, if so, I applied ZoomOut to zoom out the camera enough so that all my points were in the visible region.

```
    for (LatLng latLng : listPoints) {
                if (!(map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.contains(latLng))) {
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Apparently the problem as I understand it is that if the zoom level is for example **7.4** to correctly display all the points on the map by rounding it to the nearest integer: **7**, a valuable **.4** margin is lost than when the LiteMode This disabled is rounded to 8.

I do not know if it is the most optimal option but the problem has been solved. Any opinion is welcome! :)

Comment: Given the restrictions your solution is the best option. As this solves your issue you should accept your own answer so it can help others